# Javascript: 'return new' giving me TypeError: shape is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

Im trying to re-initing an existing shape, as a new shape below.

```
shape.init=function(a,b,c,d){
 return new shape(a,b,c,d)}

shape1=shape.init(54,63,12,13);

shape1.print();
```

When I try to call it through `shape1.print();` I get `TypeError: shape is not a constructor` and I can't seem to figure out what I've missed.

Edit:

This is the shape Im trying to re-initing.

```
var shape = new shape(54,63,12,13)
function shape(a,b,c,d){
    this.x=a
    this.y=b
    this.height=c
    this.width=d
    this.print=function()
    {return "x:"+a+", y:"+b+", height:"+c+", width:"+d}}
```

Comment: I dont see `function shape(){...}` or any other constructor function

Comment: You should call shape.init instead of shape because shape is Object not a function

Comment: `var shape = new shape(54,63,12,13)` , your can't do this, use an other identifier for your object instance. This is redefining the name of `shape` in the local scope, this can be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your code is running under the same scope, you are replacing the shape constructor by the new object you created when you did `var shape = new shape(54,63,12,13)`.

```
function shape(a,b,c,d){} // You created a constructor
...
var shape = new shape(54,63,12,13); // Shape is not a constructor anymore
                                    // but an instance of shape
...
new shape(a,b,c,d) // You cannot create an instance from another
```

Solution: Just use different variable names

```
var myshape = new shape(54,63,12,13);
myshape.init(54,63,12,13); // It works
```

Look this example http://jsfiddle.net/yu7wa2ej/

Comment: Don't think that's overriding the shape constructor .., it's hiding the shape constructor in the current scope, as it's `var shape =` and not `shape =`

Comment: Yes he is replacing by the instance obj when he does `var shape = new shape(54,63,12,13)` shape variable will be an instance. Like I've explained in my answe

Comment: what if `var shape =` is not in the same scope of the declared constructor function `shape`, this is not replacing the constructor in other scopes..

Comment: In this case you are totally right. It will just redefine the name in the local scope. But anyway, the solution is always use different identifiers :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to used different identifiers as you suggested here and it did solve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something in the order you wrote the script 'cause this works fine:

```
function shape(a, b, c, d) {
    this.x = a
    this.y = b
    this.height = c
    this.width = d
    this.print = function() {
        return "x:" + a + ", y:" + b + ", height:" + c + ", width:" + d;
    }
}
shape.init = function(a, b, c, d) {
    return new shape(a, b, c, d)
}

shape1 = shape.init(54, 63, 12, 13);

console.log(shape1.print());
```